# bash: find and copy stopped working in bash after moving script to different directory

Tags: bash, copy, find

I'm very much a rookie on bash, but after a lot of googling, I came up with this script to copy a bunch of files who's filenames are listed in a text file from a source directory (i.e. the directory where the script is being executed from) into a destination directory passed as an argument.

This worked just fine for the first group of files I used this script with. But after copying the script to a different directory and trying with a different set of files, it stopped working.

The strange thing is, if I just call `find` with one of the filenames listed in the textfile, the command finds the specified file, so I don't think the problem is that it is not finding the files.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I've updated the script per recommendation of the comments and added `-print` to the find statement. Still no output

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "ARGUMENTS INCORRECT"
    echo "USAGE: bash copyScript.sh <list_of_filenames> <files_destination_address>"
    exit 1
fi
file=$1
while read -r line; do
# echo -e "finding $line"
find -iname "$line" -print -exec cp {} "$2" \;
done <$file
```

Comment: For now, add -print and observe. `find -iname "$line" -print -exec cp {} $2 \;`

Comment: I added the -print and got no output still. Updated the script in the original post

Comment: You might add `set -x` on the  line after the shebang (#!/bin/bash) to enable xtrace output.   Do the filenames have spaces?   You might try double quoting your bash variables as well

Comment: no spaces on the input files. Aren't my bash variables double quoted already?? or are you talking about the $1??

Comment: I've enabled xtrace output as reommended by @j_b. 

I get a bunch of lines showing the correct files like this:

+ find -iname $'my_file_name_01.cs\r' -print -exec cp '{}' correct/path/to/destination/. ';'
+ read line

does this tell you anything?

Comment: Yes, the "$1" in particular.  You might also try pasting your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and implementing any recommendations.

Comment: The '\r' in the file name 1$'my_file_name_01.cs\r'` is intentional?

Comment: If the file specified by $1 contains only one line `*` then it should find all files under current directory. Check it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they are intentional. I think the \r is comming from the fact that the textfile from the input is a windows file. All this is being executed by the bash environment provided by mingw that comes with the installation of git. I suspect the \r might be messing me up :(

Comment: Yes, windows line endings can definitely be a problem.  You should be able to find a resource to convert the input file online.  Try searching for `dos2unix

Comment: Yep. Thanks for pointing out the \r. That was definitely the problem. I used dos2unix and everything works just fine. Thanks again!!

Comment: _fter copying the script to a different directory_  : Unless you are doing really fancy things in your script (such as querying the location of the script), it does not matter where the script is stored. The more important point is: Did you ensure to execute your script always from the same working directory? After all, your script has dependencies to your working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments!!

Especially to @j_b in the comment section for pointing out the carriage return character that lead me to the source of my problem.

My script has been correct the whole time. The problem was that the input text file comes from a windows system, and it had carriage return line endings (CRLF), but this being a bash script, was expecting an input text file with unix line endings (LF).

I used dos2unix tool to convert my input textfile and everything worked as intended.